# MySQL: Combine different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm having the following database structure:

```
categories
 -id
 -name

videos
 -id
 -name
 -category

pictures
 -id
 -name
 -category
```

I want to know, how much videos and pictures every category has.

I've tried an easy left join from categories to pictures and videos, but that return wrong values. Is it possible to get the COUNT() of each in only 1 sql command?

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION should work:

```
SELECT c.name, count(*) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM videos
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM pictures) AS all
      LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id=all.category
GROUP BY c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 categories.name, COUNT(videos.id) AS video_count, COUNT(pictures.id) AS picture_count
 FROM categories
 INNER JOIN videos
 ON categories.id = videos.category
 INNER JOIN pictures
 ON categories.id = pictures.category
 GROUP BY categories.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get both in the same query. Try this:

```
SELECT c.name,COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) as Videos,count(DISTINCT p.id) as Pictures
FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN videos v on v.category=c.id
LEFT JOIN Picture p on p.category=c.id
GROUP BY c.name
```